# UICollectionView cell label text not extended properly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView cell I want to extend when user tap on it. There is a label with text inside that cell, and I need to expand label text when user tap on the text.

Cell is expanded on `didSelectItemAt` but layout is not updated and it messes with the next cell. Text is all over the next cell below.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? TextCell {
        // we expand text of the label based on numberOfLines
        cell.textLbl.numberOfLines = cell.textLbl.numberOfLines == 0 ? 5 : 0
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            if let text = self.texts?[indexPath.item].text {
                cell.height = self.estimateFrameForText(text: text).height + 50
                print(cell.height)
            }

            cell.textLbl.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to refresh your layout.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```